# What would be walking speed in low gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, biophysics

In $1g$ the average adult human walks 4-5 km in an hour. How fast would such a human walk in a low gravity environment such as on the Moon $(0.17g)$ or Titan $(0.14g)$?

Let's ignore the effects of uneven terrain (regolith or ice/snow/sooth); suppose our human walks on hardened pavement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://jp.physoc.org/content/528/3/657.full) suggests that the walking speed in lower $g$ environments is indeed *less* than on 1$g$ environments.

The issue at hand is the work done in raising ones leg in order to move forwards and the loss of energy due to the motion. Quoting the article,

> During a walking step, in contrast [to the running step], the centre of mass of the body is lowered during the forward acceleration and raised during the forward deceleration. Therefore the kinetic energy loss can be transformed into a potential energy increase: $ΔE_p = MgS_v$, where $g$ is the acceleration of gravity and $S_v$ is the vertical displacement of the centre of mass within each step.

The potential energy must be equated to the kinetic energy, 
$$
\Delta E=\frac12M\left(v_2^2-v_1^2\right)
$$
where $v_2$ is the maximal velocity of the body in the step and $v_1$ the minimal velocity of the step. If we equate the two changes in energy and assume some median velocity of the body during the step, then
$$
v_{med}\sim\sqrt{2gS_v}
$$
Since $g$ decreases on the lighter bodies, then $v_{med}$ would necessarily decrease as well.

Comment: Wouldn't $S_v$ also change when walking on a different body? In particular, wouldn't it increase on a body with lower $g$ if the same vertical force is exerted by the legs?

Comment: @Wouter: I don't see how $S_v$ could change since it's basically the subject's stride. As little as it could change compared to $g$, I'd says it's a non-issue.

Comment: As I understand it, $S_v$ is basically the difference between the maximum and minimum vertical displacement of the subject's pelvis. If the subject doesn't adjust their stride and steps forward with the same vertical force as they would on earth, I'd say that difference would certainly change. Though whether the change would be large enough to affect $v_{med}$ is indeed questionable and the article you linked does seem to suggest the answer is 'no'.

Comment: @Wouter: I said stride, but it is really the vertical lift. Note, though, that the article relates $S_v$ with the leg length and its horizontal displacement in the step, so it is kinda related to stride (but more accurately as vertical displacement).

Comment: @Wouter I *think* the idea is if you kept the same force and duration then in low enough gravity that would no longer be "walking" but rather something more like skipping. The authors' definition of walking is based on body dimensions, not muscle exertion.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yeah, the motion wouldn't look like walking anymore. Though that'd be a speed I'd also be interested in: how fast would I go if I didn't adjust my muscle exertion to the situation? I reckon it'd be an uncomfortable way of moving around and probably tough to control experimentally, but if possible I think it should be considered nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

With lower gravity like that on the moon traction becomes an issue.  It appears the individual is forced "Hop" each step or else shuffle slowly to keep from bounching. Technically they are no longer walking, but either hopping or shuffling.  A true walk would be slow going only for reason of traction I would imagine.

Barring that, one may argue that walking speed is more related to gait than gravity.  For example; 170lb Soldier A carrying 60lbs can walk at the same pace (4-5km/h) as Soldier B carrying no extra weight.  The difference only becomes apparent when Soldier A requires more frequent rest stops, water, and calorie intake. Overall distance covered by Soldier A will be less, though the walking pace may be equal.